# how to add 2 overlapping elements in a div?

Tags: css, html, overlapping

```
<div id="parent" style="height:250px;width:250px;display:inline">
   <div id="child" style="height:100%;width:100%;z-index:10001"></div>
   <select style="height:100%;width:100%;z-index:10000"><option/></select>
</div>
```

My requirement is to include the select and child div elements inside the parent div in such a way that the child div is on top of the select element and completely covers it. Later I want to hide the child div based on an event and make the select element visible.
Both child div and select elements should occupy the entire size of parent div each on their own.
how can I achieve this?

Comment: looks like my code was not added to the question when I posted it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dyBjZ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking input from the comments above, I was able to solve my problem. Here is what I did. Posting it here in case someone else lands up on this page searching.

```
<div id="parent" style="height:250px;width:250px">
    <div id="child" style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%"></div>
    <div id="selectParent" style="display:none;height:100%;width:100%">
      <select><option/></select>
    <div>
</div>
```

Based on the javascript event, I toggle display from block to none for child div. And toggle display from none to block in selectParent.

Comment: @isherwood, I was looking to set both the child elements to the exact size of the parent and then toggle their visibility based on events. I included your CSS changes here now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/dyBjZ/2

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <select>
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="child" id="child">Click me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue is to give the `#parent` div a size, thus remove `display: inline` from its style.

Next, you could toggle for both elements from `display: none` to `display: block`, and v.v. But to reduce this by half, you could use absolute positioning which takes the element out of the default markup layout, as shown in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/LX6Gw/).

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child"></div>
   <select></select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    background: #aaa;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
select {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#child.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```